# Injecting a custom sql query into a page/theme

Tags: theme-development, hooks, child-theme, pre-get-posts, child-pages

I have written a custom sql query for our WordPress website (fairly elaborate and not achievable with the standard wordpress code) and I've got it to run via `$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($query, OBJECT);`, it yields the results I expect. Now I would like to integrate this query via a hook (ideally), so that I don't have to update the theme page so that we can still update the theme. I know that the hook `pre_get_posts()` allows you to adjust the main query, but from what I've found it seems to **only** allow you **adjust**. E.g. `$query->set( 'year', $today['year'] );`. I however, want to replace the query completely.

Is this doable using a hook so that I can utilize the main theme code using a hook from my child theme code?

Or will I need to clone the full page from the main theme to the child theme and use the code like this:

```
<?php 
$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($q, OBJECT);
if ($pageposts):
    global $post;
    foreach ($pageposts as $post):
        setup_postdata($post);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hooks you are looking for can be found in the WordPress Codex [`WP_Query` - Filters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Filters):

> #### Filters
>
> - [posts_distinct](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_distinct) - Alters SQL 'DISTINCTROW' clause to the query that returns the post array.
> - [posts_groupby](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_groupby) - Alters SQL 'GROUP BY' clause of the query that returns the post array.
> - [posts_join](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_join) - Alters SQL 'JOIN' clause of the query that returns the post array.
> - [post_limits](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/post_limits) - Alters SQL 'LIMIT' clause of the query that returns the post array.
> - [posts_orderby](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_orderby) - Alters SQL 'ORDER BY' clause of the query that returns the post array.
> - [posts_where](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where) - Alters SQL 'WHERE' clause of the query that returns the post array.
> - [posts_join_paged](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_join_paged) - Alters SQL paging for posts using 'JOIN' clause of the query that returns the post array.
> - [posts_where_paged](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where_paged) - Alters SQL paging for posts using 'WHERE' clause of the query that returns the post array.
> - [posts_clauses](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_clauses) - Alters all the SQL clauses above in one go. It gives you an array of elements that are easy to alter (available with
>     [Version 3.1](http://codex.wordpress.org/Version_3.1)).
>
> Note, that there are more filters than the mentioned. As it is hard to
>   keep the codex up to date, please inspect the `get_posts();` function
>   inside the WP_Query class yourself (/wp-includes/query.php).

Firstly, as the Note says, there are more filters than mentioned and, secondly, from the mentioned filters are not all documented. You can do a lot with those included in above list, but it might be necessary to take a look at the source [`query.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/query.php#L0) yourself, to find all possibilities you have.

Therefore, without knowing your SQL and your exact plans, I assume you can do what you want by using one or more of those hooks. After you gathered the information you need for your use case take a look around/search here on WPSE for similar implementations, there are plenty of suggested approaches for different scenarios, so you might just find what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've added another question regarding the query itself here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22959765/stacking-mysql-results
This will give a little background on the query I'm running

Comment: My pleasure, giving it a very quick glance I'd say, this a bit more complex use case for sure, but as far as I can tell should be possible via using hooks and altering the query. Good luck! @Richard